# Form Data Gets Inserted Into MySQL Table But Still Server Throws Error

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I want to insert some values into my book table and I created a PHP page with HTML form inside it. The problem is my values gets inserted but it throws a primary key error on the webpage. The code is as below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>New Books</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $server="localhost";
        $username="root";
        $password="";
        $db="library";

        $conn= new mysqli($server,$username,$password,$db);
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
          echo "Server Error Occured Please Try Again Later";
        }

        $bid=$_POST['bid'];
        $bname=$_POST['bname'];
        $baut=$_POST['baut'];
        $bc=$_POST['bc'];
        $blf=$_POST['blf'];
        $bs=$_POST['bs'];

        $sql="insert into books(BOOK_ID,BOOK_NAME,BOOK_AUTHOR,BOOK_CATEGORY,BOOK_LOST_FINE, BOOK_STATUS) values('$bid','$bname','$baut','$bc','$blf','$bs')";
        $result=$conn->query($sql);

        if ($conn->query($sql)===TRUE) {
          echo "New Book Added Successfully";
        }
        else{
          echo "Please Recheck The Values Entered" . $conn->error;
          $secondsWait = 5;
          header("Refresh:$secondsWait");
        }
      }
    ?>
    <div class="header">
      <a href="images/456.jpg" class="logo">Lowa State University</a>
      <div class="header-right">
        <a class="active" href="#">Main Page</a>
        <a href="contacts.html">Due Fines</a>
        <a href="aboutus.html">Contact Us</a>
        <a href="">Profile</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="bid" placeholder="BOOK ID"><br><br>
      <input type="text" name="bname" placeholder="BOOK NAME"><br><br>
      <input type="text" name="baut" placeholder="BOOK AUTHOR"><br><br>
      <input type="text" name="bc" placeholder="BOOK CATEGORY"><br><br>
      <input type="number" name="blf" placeholder="BOOK LOST FINE"><br><br>
      <input type="text" name="bs" placeholder="BOOK STATUS"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Book"><br><br>
      <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear Fields">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**SAMPLE VALUES IN FORM**
[image]

Now if I press the add button this error shows up:

**Error Image:**

[image]

but the values are already entered into the SQL table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like hingu Devang and Bira mentioned, make your ID column Auto_Increment and do not manually place a value there because it will automatically assign a value.

As for your issue that the query is being executed twice, try removing the line:

```
$result=$conn->query($sql);
```

Because you already have a query which is:

```
if($conn->query($sql)===TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you add any field as primary key that mean it must have unique record, **no duplication allowed**. you trying to add duplicate(same record) in same table.

 
You should add BOOK_ID as **primary key + auto increment** in database and when you insert new record, you don't need to add BOOK_ID manually at code. i automatically incremented from previous record and added automatically.

Just do like this

```
 $sql="insert into 
    books(BOOK_NAME,BOOK_AUTHOR,BOOK_CATEGORY,BOOK_LOST_FINE,
    BOOK_STATUS) values('$bname','$baut','$bc','$blf','$bs')";
```

and remove following line **`$result=$conn->query($sql);`**

**Note [add `BOOK_ID` AS PRIMARY KEY + AUTO INCREMENT in *Table*]**

Comment: yes i have created my table like that now but still my query is being executed twice. this started to happen after i added the ISSET function to my code to execute the sql query after i press the submit button.